# github ssh publickey permission denied

Tags: git, ssh-keys

I have a server on which I have checkout a git repository. I usually ssh into this server from my desktop and work in my repository and push and pull changes from github. Now I am sshed into this same server from my laptop (this laptop has the same private and public ssh keys as my desktop) and when I try to do a git pull from this same server that I always do a git pull on (although I have sshed into the server from a different machine) I am getting a permission denied (publickey) error.

Based on everything I know about git and ssh keys this seems absurd. What could I be missing?

Comment: Have the permissions on your ~/.ssh dir changed?

Comment: Is your `HOME` correctly set once you are sshed on the server? Does `$HOME/.ssh` contains the right GitHub credentials? (I suppose you are pulling GitHub from your sshed server, right?)